# Unable to plot graph on matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am new to Python and I am having some problems with plotting graphs on matplotlib which I hope you all can assist me.

So I have a DataFrame that shows the temperature in a given year.

```
    01-01    334
    01-02    320
    01-03    330
    01-04    331
    01-05    328
          .
          .
          .
    12-27    318
    12-28    320
    12-29    320
    12-30    325
    12-31    334
```

and when I try to plot it by using the following codes:

```
 dates = pd.date_range('1/1/2015','31/12/2015', freq = 'D')
 yvals = list(df.values)
 plt.figure()
 plt.plot(dates,'-', yvals, '-')
```

It just returns a white figure with no points or lines on it.

How do I go about resolving this?? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Its not clear what your `df.values` is, but I suspect it is your second DataFrame column?
In that case you can just use the [DataFrame.plot()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html#pandas.DataFrame.plot) method.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `matplotlib`, you can try to use `plt.show()`:

```
plt.figure()
sample_image = plt.plot(x,y)
plt.imshow(sample_image) 
plt.show()  # display it
```

*Note*: Be aware that you don't have to show the image in order to save it.

```
plt.savefig('image.png')
```

Answer (score 0):

you should either convert the dates to numbers, or use plt.plot_dates:

```
dates = pd.date_range('1/1/2015' ,'31/12/2015', freq = 'D')
yvals = np.linspace(1,366,365)
plt.plot_date(dates ,yvals)
plt.show()
```

(I didn't know what your yvals were so I made them up. should work with yours too)
Read the plot_date documentation for more details

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is `plt.plot(x, y, style)`

Try

```
plt.plot(dates, yvals, '-')
```